# how to make a graph with dynamic x,y axis using canvas tag html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to make a graph which plots numeric points like (23,45),(32,67) etc using canvas tag in html5. I found this graph in this link http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/draw-a-line-graph-using-html5-canvas/ The problem in this graph is that only y-axis works with numeric values.I want to make X-axis work with numeric values as well using the same logic as y-axis...Please help

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear. The x axis in that example is already dynamic actually. Check out the demo here [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/m6Lgn/1/)

Comment: i want to make x axis values numeric as well just like y axis.Currently it displays months.I want to plot points in a graph like(55,60) (45,23) using the concepts of the example given in the link i posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really easy fix. The as it is graphing, it just references the length of the data instead of the X values. We can work around this easily by adding a `getMaxX()` function, and referencing the actual X values. [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/crzyman/nshX6/1).

Comment: In this code the scale of X-axis is not even i.e the spacing between the texts of X value is not equal..Tried editing the code but still no difference..

Comment: Technically, the scale is even, but the spacing of the numbers was not. If a number was skipped, it wasn't shown, but all of the other numbers were in their correct position. I edited the code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/crzyman/nshX6/5/), and I got it to do what I believe you were looking for. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I know this question is a little old, but is there a way to adjust the x and y axes so they extend into negatives?

Comment: Absolutely! The only question you will have to answer first is how you want the vertical axis to look. I'm working on an example right now, hold on. http://jsfiddle.net/nshX6/32/ there you go. You just need to use the range instead of the Maximum X value, and then you need to shift the numbers on the X-axis based on the minimum. I'll leave the Y-axis to you ;)